# The scheme of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

In the tutorial, they call functions in this order:

- constructor()
- static getDerivedStateFromProps()
- render()
- componentDidMount()

Why fetch and assigning value to state is done in `componentDidMount()` if the place where it is needed, or `render()` occurs earlier?

**I have a very complex object and I would not want to create it with empty fields at the beginning in state**

The object contains several collections with other objects, etc.

Calling the method in the constructor will not work

Comment: I think, judging by your bolding, your question is why `render()` is firing before the state is set in those other functions?

Answer (score 0):

In app runtime envirenment we have two threads

1. Main thread responsible to execute the native code.
2. JS thread responsible to execute javascript code.

If we call an API in the render function.

```js
render(){
  //API call
  return(<View/>) 
}
```

API call is made in javaScript So, JS Thread will be responsible to execute  the code and Main Thread will wait till the API response is sent by the JS Thread. During this time your UI will be unresponsive. Your app won't respond to any UI interaction.

That's why the API calls are made in the componentDidMount.